# Convert relative time to datetime in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, offset, relative-date

How can I convert a relative date/time string to a real date/time in Javascript (can use libraries)

For example, the user will input into an edit field any of the following examples (among others):
THIS IS THE INPUT:

- 2 weeks ago
- Last 3 weeks
- 24 hours ago
- Last 4 months
- Last week
- Last monday

So, taking now/todays datetime as a starting point, I need to get the date/time they are referring to.
So is today is 2018-04-06 11:19 and they enter '1 week ago' or 'a week ago' then I need a routine which will return

- '2018-03-30 11:19'

as the OUTPUT

I know about moment.js and how to use that to change a date/time/moment to a relative datetime, but I need it done the other way around, - to change a relative date string to a date/time.

EDIT:
I have now found :
  - https://github.com/wanasit/chrono

which seems to solve the problem.

Comment: See moment [`calendar()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/) and please show what did you tried so far.

Comment: Thanks. calendar() seems to be for display, rather than parsing. I have been looking for a library to parse relative dates to a normal date string but cant find any yet.

Comment: I have now found : - https://github.com/wanasit/chrono

which seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/wanasit/chrono   This library seems to provide exactly as was requested in the OP.  The input is a relative date in Natural Language (almost) and the output is a date.